# Rendering to HTML canvas in recursive calls

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have implemented a recursive maze generation algorithm in Javascript, and am rendering using HTML canvas.

The problem I have, is that I am unable to render to the canvas while the recursive function is in progress. The render only appears after recursive calls have finished.

Here is my (rough) functioning recursive function :

```
    function start(canvas_context)
{
    //do some stuff here...
    render(canvas_context);
    if()...{

        start(canvas_context);
    }
    else if(...)
    {
        if(...)
        {
            start(canvas_context);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my rendering function:

```
    function render(canvas_context)
{
    canvas_context.fillStyle = 'black';
    canvas_context.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for(..)
    {
        for(...)
        {
            canvas_context.strokeStyle = 'red';
            canvas_context.beginPath();
            canvas_context.moveTo(start.x, start.y);
            canvas_context.lineTo(end.x,end.y);
            canvas_context.stroke();
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the full functions if they are needed:

```
    function start(canvas_context)
{
    //Vector2.print(game_config["current_grid_pos"]);
    var current_block = game_config["grid_space"][game_config["current_grid_pos"].y][game_config["current_grid_pos"].x];
    var random_neighbor_grid_pos = random_neighbor(current_block);
    //render(canvas_context);
    if(random_neighbor_grid_pos.x != -1 && random_neighbor_grid_pos.y != -1)
    {
        var next_block = game_config["grid_space"][random_neighbor_grid_pos.y][random_neighbor_grid_pos.x];
        next_block.visited = true;
        game_config["visited_stack"].push(random_neighbor_grid_pos);
        remove_walls(current_block, next_block);
        game_config["current_grid_pos"] = random_neighbor_grid_pos;
        start(canvas_context);
    }
    else if (game_config["visited_stack"].length > 0)
    {
        current_block.visited = true;
        game_config["visited_stack"].pop();
        if(game_config["visited_stack"].length != 0)
        {
            game_config["current_grid_pos"] = game_config["visited_stack"][game_config["visited_stack"].length - 1];
            start(canvas_context);
        }
    }
}


    function render(canvas_context)
{
    //Initialise the canvas background.
    canvas_context.fillStyle = 'black';
    canvas_context.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for(var y = 0; y < game_config["grid_space"].length; y++)
    {
        for(var x = 0; x < game_config["grid_space"][0].length; x++)
        {
            var block = game_config["grid_space"][y][x];
            var walls = block.get_walls();
            for(var key in walls)
            {
                var wall = walls[key];
                render_line(canvas_context, wall.start, wall.end);
            }
        }

    }
}

    function render_line(canvas_context, start, end)
{
    canvas_context.strokeStyle = 'red';
    canvas_context.beginPath();
    canvas_context.moveTo(start.x, start.y);
    canvas_context.lineTo(end.x,end.y);
    canvas_context.stroke();

}
```

Is it even possible to render during recursive calls with HTML canvas?

Comment: Yes, it's possible; the canvas API has no idea how or when it's being called. You left out an awful lot of detail in the code.

Comment: @Pointy I've added the full implementations if that helps

Comment: @Pointy What do you mean when you say that the canvas API has no idea how or when its being called?

Comment: @DaniilLoban But isn't clearing necessary? Otherwise, I would be keeping all previous draws. The state of the screen has renderables so I need to draw everything again?

Comment: What I mean is that the calling environment (like, from a function that's been called recursively) is not detectable by any code that implements the API.

Comment: If you expect to see pixels being drawn little by little, that isn't going to happen. Filling in your grid will happen in almost no time. Generally browsers don't repaint the window in the middle of an event loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it without a `recursion` but I show **both ways**:

```js
    const cellsise = 10;    
    class block {
      constructor (x, y){
        this.x = x;
        this. y = y;
        this.delta = {x: x * cellsise , y: y * cellsise};
        this.walls = {
          left: {
            start: {
              x: 0 + this.delta.x,
              y: 0 + this.delta.y
            },
            end: {
              x: 0 + this.delta.x,
              y: cellsise + this.delta.y
            }
          },
          top: {
            start: {
              x: 0 + this.delta.x, 
              y: 0 + this.delta.y
            },
            end: {
              x: cellsise + this.delta.x,
              y: 0 + this.delta.y
            }
          },
          right:  {
            start: {
              x: cellsise + this.delta.x,
              y: 0 + this.delta.y
            },
            end: {
              x: cellsise + this.delta.x,
              y: cellsise + this.delta.y
            }
          },
          bottom: {
            start: {
              x: 0 + this.delta.x,
              y: cellsise + this.delta.y
            },
            end: {
              x: cellsise + this.delta.x,
              y: cellsise + this.delta.y
            }
          }
        };
      }
      get_walls(){
        return this.walls;
      } 
    }

    const game_config = {
      grid_space:[],

      height: 10,
      width: 10,
    }

    function generateGridSpace() {
      game_config.grid_space=[];
      for(y = 0 ; y < game_config.height; ++y){
        game_config.grid_space.push([]);
        for(x = 0 ; x < game_config.width; ++x){
          game_config.grid_space[y].push(new block(x, y))
        }
      }
    }

    function remove_walls(current_block){
      let left = Math.random() > 0.5;
      let top = !left //Math.random() > 0.5;
      let right = Math.random() > 0.5;
      let bottom = !right //false// Math.random() > 0.5;
      
      if (left && current_block.x - 1 > 0) {
        delete current_block.walls.left;
        delete game_config.grid_space[current_block.x-1][current_block.y].walls.right
      }
      if (top && current_block.y - 1 > 0) {
        delete current_block.walls.top;
        delete game_config.grid_space[current_block.x][current_block.y-1].walls.bottom;
      }
      
      if (right && current_block.x+1 < game_config.width -1) {
        delete current_block.walls.right;
        delete game_config.grid_space[current_block.x + 1][current_block.y].walls.left;
      }
      if (bottom && current_block.y+1 < game_config.height -1) {
        delete current_block.walls.bottom;
        delete game_config.grid_space[current_block.x][current_block.y + 1].walls.top;
      }
      
    }
    
  function start_with_recursion(canvas_context, mix=null) {
    if (!mix) {
      mix = game_config.grid_space.reduce((acc, e) => [...acc,...e], [])
      .sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)
    } else if (mix.length === 0) {
       return;
    }
    
    const block = mix.pop();
    const i = game_config.width * game_config.height - mix.length

    setTimeout(() => {
      remove_walls(block);
      render_block(canvas_context, block);
    },  i * 50)

    start_with_recursion(canvas_context, mix)
  }

  function start_without_recursion(canvas_context) {
    const  mix = game_config.grid_space.reduce((acc, e) => [...acc,...e], [])
      .sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)
    for(let i = 0; i < mix.length; ++i){
      setTimeout(() => {
        remove_walls(mix[i]);
        render_block(canvas_context, mix[i]);
      }, i * 50)
    }
  }

  function render_block(canvas_context, block) {
    var walls = block.get_walls();
    for(var key in walls)
    {
      var wall = walls[key];
      render_line(canvas_context, wall.start, wall.end);
    }
  }

  function render_line(canvas_context, start, end) {
    canvas_context.strokeStyle = 'red';
    canvas_context.beginPath();
    canvas_context.moveTo(
      5 + start.x  + .5,
      5 + start.y  + .5
    );
    canvas_context.lineTo(
      5 + end.x + .5,
      5 + end.y + .5
    );
    canvas_context.stroke();
  }

  canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
  canvas.height = game_config.height * cellsise + 5 * 2;
  canvas.width = game_config.width * cellsise + 5 * 2;
  ctx =  canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
  // ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  generateGridSpace();
  // start_without_recursion(ctx);
  start_with_recursion(ctx);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

also for get a random neighbor:

```
  function random_neighbor(current_block) {
    const {height, width} = game_config;
    const neighbors = [
      {x: current_block.x, y: current_block.y - 1}, // from top
      {x: current_block.x - 1, y: current_block.y}, // from left
      {x: current_block.x + 1, y: current_block.y}, // from right
      {x: current_block.x, y: current_block.y + 1}, // from bottom
    ].filter(e => e.x >= 0 && e.x < width &&  e.y >= 0 && e.y < height)
    const rnd = neighbors[Math.floor(Math.random() * neighbors.length)]
    return rnd; // {x, y}
  }
```

You also need to take into account that the drawn wall can be removed later, which will not correspond to reality. Therefore, it is better to render (even with a delay) after the maze is fully generated.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest converting your recursive function into an iterator function, and then introducing a second function that makes use of `setInterval` to iteratively draw your maze, and once complete, then performs a `clearInterval`.

Here's a quick sample that I whipped up exemplifying the concept, which simply draws increasingly larger rectangles on the canvas every 50ms, with the iterator function returning the size of the next rectangle to be drawn.  In your case, you'll likely want to yield an object defining the portion of the maze to be drawn...

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');

function* recurse( n, max ) {
  yield n;
  if ( n < max ) {
    yield* recurse( n + 1, max );
  }
}

function drawRectangles() {

  function drawIteratively() {
    let nd = iterator.next();  
    if ( nd.done ) {
      clearInterval( interval );
    } else {
      ctx.lineWidth = 1;
      ctx.strokeStyle = '#FF0000';
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rect( nd.value, nd.value, nd.value * 2, nd.value * 2 );
      ctx.stroke();
    } 
  }

  let iterator = recurse( 25, 100 );
  let interval = setInterval( drawIteratively, 50 );
}

drawRectangles();
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas' width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Note that the iterator function is a very basic recursive function, but recursive nonetheless, showing the critical syntax involved in a recursive iterator function...